# Uncaught ReferenceError: <something> is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

In my [github project](https://github.com/sybind/doorcountytrees.com), am receiving the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: breakpoints is not defined` in the chrome console. This should be resolved from the `breakpoints.min.js`, but webpack is somehow breaking/mangling it.

I think it has something to do with webpack and how I am importing the static js files from the [theme](https://html5up.net/massively) I downloaded.

`breakpoints` resolves if I paste the original `breakpoints.min.js` content into the chrome console.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  entry: {
      './js/app.js': ['./js/app.js'].concat(glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js'))
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ]
});
```

Am not seeing any errors in the webpack debug output:

```
Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: e70b0e57a305a5ee940a
Version: webpack 4.4.0
Time: 2890ms
Built at: 5/7/2019 9:08:20 PM
                Asset       Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
       ../css/app.css    113 KiB  ./js/app.js  [emitted]  ./js/app.js
               app.js    351 KiB  ./js/app.js  [emitted]  ./js/app.js
       ../favicon.ico   1.23 KiB               [emitted]
../images/overlay.png   2.74 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic02.jpg   20.2 KiB               [emitted]
../images/phoenix.png   13.6 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic01.jpg   59.5 KiB               [emitted]
     ../images/bg.jpg    396 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic03.jpg   20.2 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic04.jpg   20.3 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic08.jpg   13.1 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic06.jpg   20.6 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic05.jpg   20.7 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic07.jpg   20.7 KiB               [emitted]
  ../images/pic09.jpg   12.7 KiB               [emitted]
        ../robots.txt  202 bytes               [emitted]
   [0] multi ./js/app.js ./vendor/js/breakpoints.min.js ./vendor/js/browser.min.js ./vendor/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js ./vendor/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js ./vendor/js/main.js ./vendor/js/util.js 100 bytes {./js/app.js} [built]
[../deps/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js] 2.21 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
[./css/app.css] 39 bytes {./js/app.js} [built]
[./js/app.js] 493 bytes {./js/app.js} [built]
[./vendor/js/breakpoints.min.js] 4.25 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
[./vendor/js/browser.min.js] 2.76 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
[./vendor/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js] 3.3 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
[./vendor/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js] 1.25 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
[./vendor/js/main.js] 4.92 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
[./vendor/js/util.js] 11.3 KiB {./js/app.js} [built]
    + 6 hidden modules
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!css/app.css:
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/app.css] 455 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/font-awesome.min.css] 32.4 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/main.css] 99.2 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/noscript.css] 1.12 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

**EDIT:**

`breakpoints` is called in `main.js` in line 17. From the webpack console output, `breakpoints.min.js` appears to load before `main.js` as can be see above.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I guess that you have to manage the order of the scripts, because it looks like your main script is bundled **before** than the vendor's library so that your variable is really undefined

Comment: changed the order around, and still encountering the same error. `[0] multi ./vendor/js/breakpoints.min.js ./vendor/js/browser.min.js ./vendor/js/jquery.min.js ./vendor/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js ./vendor/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js ./vendor/js/main.js ./vendor/js/util.js 100 bytes {vendor} [built]`

Comment: Can you show me where you include the breakpoints file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },

  entry: {
    'vendor': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js'),
    './js/app.js':  ['./js/app.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work. I'm still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

How are you using `breakpoints`?
Based on the reported error, it sounds like there is *some* script file attempting to use `breakpoints` before the file which defines it has been loaded (and run enough to define `breakpoints`).

Look at the Chrome console on the right side to see what line is throwing that error. This is the code which is running before that definition.  Make sure that code does not run until after the file defining `breakpoints` has finished loading.

Comment: `breakpoints` is called in `main.js` in line 17. From the webpack console output, `breakpoints.min.js` appears to load before `main.js` as noted above.